# elasticsearch not returning array values

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch

I am trying to return a mongodb document from elasticsearch. The document is being returned but the arrays are always empty e.g.

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/smartjn/feed_details/_search?q=_id:577905710baf751293410bed&pretty=true'
{
  "took" : 3,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [ {
      "_index" : "smartjn",
      "_type" : "feed_details",
      "_id" : "577905710baf751293410bed",
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "_source" : {
        "rejectionId" : "",
        "image" : [ ],
        "subward" : "56a6124244fc868a255fe3fe",
        "longi" : "72.8179",
        "subDepartment" : "Environment",
        "vote" : 0,
        "workFlowType" : "Event",
        "wardname" : "Dhokali",
        "title" : "Test Feed for MassUpload :925",
        "approvalStatus" : "approved",
        "adminFlag" : "1",
        "userID" : "superadmin",
        "uniquerefno" : "ED3488",
        "department" : "Social Causes",
        "upVoteUserIds" : [ ],
        "feedStatusDescription" : "03-07-2016 18:00:41",
        "description" : "Test Feed Description for MassUpload :925",
        "sorter" : "2016-07-03T18:00:40.812000",
        "downVoteUserIds" : [ ],
        "muteFeedUserIds" : [ ],
        "lat" : "18.35367",
        "dateCreated" : "03-07-2016 18:00:41",
        "muteUserIds" : [ ],
        "followFeedUserIds" : [ ],
        "feedStatus" : "New",
        "externalRefNo" : "",
        "anonymousFlag" : "0",
        "downVote" : 0
      }
    } ]
  }
}
```

Same document in mongodb returns all fields correct:

```
rs0:PRIMARY> db.feed_details.find({_id : ObjectId("577905710baf751293410bed")}).pretty()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("577905710baf751293410bed"),
        "department" : "Social Causes",
        "subDepartment" : "Environment",
        "workFlowType" : "Event",
        "lat" : "18.35367",
        "longi" : "72.8179",
        "title" : "Test Feed for MassUpload :925",
        "description" : "Test Feed Description for MassUpload :925",
        "image" : [ ],
        "userID" : "superadmin",
        "anonymousFlag" : "0",
        "approvalStatus" : "approved",
        "dateCreated" : "03-07-2016 18:00:41",
        "feedStatus" : "New",
        "vote" : 1,
        "downVote" : 0,
        "rejectionId" : "",
        "feedStatusDescription" : "03-07-2016 18:00:41",
        "followFeedUserIds" : [
                "5734236844fc869a32793b7f"
        ],
        "muteFeedUserIds" : [
                "5734236844fc869a32793b7f"
        ],
        "muteUserIds" : [ ],
        "externalRefNo" : "",
        "subward" : "56a6124244fc868a255fe3fe",
        "upVoteUserIds" : [
                "5734236844fc869a32793b7f"
        ],
        "downVoteUserIds" : [ ],
        "uniquerefno" : "ED3488",
        "adminFlag" : "1",
        "sorter" : ISODate("2016-07-03T18:00:40.812Z"),
        "wardname" : "Dhokali"
}
```

Any idea what am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: How did you index the document from Mongodb to ES?

Comment: using mongo-connector

Comment: Do you have any configuration of mongo-connector? Firstly you should check your data with `curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/smartjn/feed_details/577905710baf751293410bed'` this query. If your data really has these array the problem may be about your mapping, otherwise, you have a problem about connector.

Comment: It has the arrays but empty ones.I have opened up the issue with connector team.

Answer (score 0):

The curl request is quite not right, There's a better way of doing it.

try this

curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/smartjn/feed_details/577905710baf751293410bed'

Comment: really , I just now ran this: and the document has no changes from what posted above

Comment: @satya then there must be some problem with the indexing, are you using plugin head ? search for this document in gui and see if it's populated first

Answer (score 0):

To solve a problem, you try to understand firstly what is the problem. In this case, the problem may be your connector or your mapping. And you should give information about that to us to be able to help you.

Firstly check your real data with the following curl request:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/smartjn/feed_details/577905710baf7512‌​93410bed'
```

After that Can you see your array and content in your data. If your array is not there in the result, your problem may be about your connector. If your array is there, your problem may be your mapping.

Comment: @Satya your problem may be your connector. Try to understand, your connector can really send array content to elasticsearch. Or share with us how you run your connector.